# Is there a way to set InitialDelay for the ToolTip on a ToolStripStatusLabel?

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I have a `ToolStripStatusLabel` as an image in my `StatusStrip` that when clicked shows a log report. I also set a `ToolTip` for this element, so the user knows what happens when he clicks in there. Problem is, as it is in the bottom of my app, there's not much room for the `ToolTip` to show below the image, so it overlays the image, thus being in the way of the click.

What I want to do is increase the initial delay for the `ToolTip` to show, so the expert user will click the image before the Tip shows.

But `StatusStrip`s are tricky and I couldn't find how to set this property. Is there a way or not?

Comment: You are giving an excellent argument why a StatusStrip should never be used for anything more than showing status.  Not only is it so unintuitive that you need a tooltip to give the user a chance to discover the command, you are finding out that the tooltip actually gets in the way.  So fix the real problem, make it a button in a ToolStrip at the top of the window.

Comment: maybe create your own tooltip for that `ToolStripStatusLabel` would help.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think it's unintuitive, but I get that the control I'm trying to use was not designed for what I'm trying to do. I'll fix my design. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what you want.
The toolTip has the property InitialDelay.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.initialdelay.aspx

Comment: That's correct, but the `StatusStrip` elements don't use the `ToolTip` object to show a tool tip.